# git pull using shell script

Tags: shell, git, pull

I have a shell script that pulls my repository from git.
Normally, it receives the credentials and the pull works just fine.

My question is what happens if the credentials are wrong and I get an authentication failure. How can I catch this error and stop the shell script?

Answer (score 1):

All commands return a single-byte value (from 0 through 255) after they have completed executing. Usually a 0 return value indicates success and non-0 indicates some sort of problem. Various shells have constructs that check the 0-ness of the return value and can act upon it.

```
#!/bin/bash
if git ...
then
  echo "git succeeded"
fi

if ! git ...
then
  echo "git failed"
fi

git ... || echo "git failed"
git ... && echo "git succeeded"
```

Comment: Hi - thanks. What you wrote is working well when I execute the script form command line. However, I execute the script by using php which in this scenario I don't get the response from the git pull command. Any idea?

Comment: I'm unclear on what you're trying to do.  Are you trying to execute the script (or the `git pull`) from a PHP web page or a PHP-based command-line script?  Do you get ANY output?  Are there any errors? Can you show us exactly how you're calling the shell script using PHP?  If this is in a PHP script, a code snippet will suffice.  If you're using the php CLI, the command line should do it.  Also note there may be a MUCH better way to do what you're trying to do so you might want to consider filling in the details a bit.